# Python client for Google Container Engine API

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-api-python-client

I'm working on a project where I need to create and manage clusters, pods, services and deployments on google container engine.I have googled a lot to find an API for that, Google's Container engine REST API is available, is there any python client for that API? what I need exactly.

Help me, please!
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

On [this page](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/apis/container/v1) you can find information about using Python including installation of the client library and

> Google Container Engine API: The Google Container Engine API is used
>   for building and managing container based applications, powered by the
>   open source Kubernetes technology.
>
> This page contains information about getting started with the Google
>   Container Engine API using the Google API Client Library for Python.
>   In addition, you may be interested in the following documentation.

More generally there is [this page](https://cloud.google.com/python/apis) about Google APIs and Python libraries and [a getting started using Python in GCE example on Github](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/getting-started-python/tree/master/optional-container-engine).

Comment: how can I use this lib in python mean it's rest api not python library?

Comment: Hi, @DDay! can you help me regarding this question, please! https://stackoverflow.com/q/47149954/7644562